# WSO2 queue consume

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

i developed an Web Service in Spring TS that create an ActiveMQ Queue and API with WSO2 Integration Studio 8.0 for consume the queue and receive the queue message.

My Spring TS Web Service functions correctly, he starts and with POSTMAN i run it and then the Web Service connects to ActiveMQ for send a integer number (the result of 2 numbers sum), all is okay at this point.

After, i have and WSO2 Integration Studio API that consume a ActiveMQ queue for receive the message (in this case is about of the 2 numbers sum result) and this are do correctly but i have a problem, i when wanna deploy it in WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 7.1.0 i cant do it because my project is Java Application based and Enterprise Integrator dont have support to Java Application and for the nature of my project cant either have a Compositer Exporter folder for generate CAR file to import my integration to WSO2 Enterprise Integrator, i have understanted that for can implement a flow in a Micro Integrator enviroment i should develop it with mediators integration flows and endpoints in a Integration Project for i can have a Compositer Exporter folder in where i can generate a CAR file with which i can import my project to the Enterprise Integrator enviroment, well the JAVA Application code with which get the queue message for queue consume is the next:

```
package getQueueMsg;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class ActiveMQConsumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String brokerUrl = "tcp://localhost:61616"; // Broker URL ActiveMQ

        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);

        try {
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            // Set the Queue name to consult
            Destination destination = session.createQueue("SumResult");

            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

            // Read the queue messages
            while (true) {
                Message message = consumer.receive();
                // Process the message about your needs
                System.out.println("Mensaje recibido: " + message.toString());
            }

            // Close the connection and free the resources
            //session.close();
            //connection.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

with this java code i consume correctly the queue but the problem is for the nature of the project which is Java Application based i cant generate CAR file to then deploy it in Enterprise Integrator enviroment.
Can someone guide to me to starts do a flow to do the same that i do trought mi JAVA code but using a integration flow based in mediators on a Integration Project for this way i can generate an CAR file for deploy it in a Enterprise Integrator enviroment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't Java code like the one mentioned within Micro Integrator. Inorder to consume JMS messages from ActiveMQ you will have to develop an integration flow. You can either user a [Listener Proxy](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/setup/brokers/configure-with-ActiveMQ/#setting-up-the-micro-integrator-with-activemq).

```xml
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="JMStoHTTPStockQuoteProxy"
       transports="jms"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="transactionID"
                   expression="get-property('MessageID')"
                   scope="default"/>
         <property name="sourceMessageID"
                   expression="get-property('MessageID')"
                   scope="default"/>
         <property name="proxyMessageID"
                   expression="get-property('MessageID')"
                   scope="default"/>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="transactionID" expression="get-property('transactionID')"/>
            <property name="sourceMessageID" expression="get-property('sourceMessageID')"/>
            <property name="MessageID" expression="get-property('proxyMessageID')"/>
         </log>
         <property name="SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <drop/>               
      </inSequence>
      <faultSequence name="jms_fault"/>
   </target>
   <parameter name="redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries">1</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionTransacted">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">JMStoHTTPStockQuoteProxy</parameter>
   <parameter name="redeliveryPolicy.redeliveryDelay">2000</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.CacheLevel">consumer</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Or you can create an [Inbound Endpoint](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/synapse-properties/inbound-endpoints/polling-inbound-endpoints/jms-inbound-endpoint-properties/) to listen to the ActiveMQ queue. I would recommend this option over the proxy.